# Difference between in-process and out-process service

Tags: process

What are applications that run "in-process" vs those that run "out-process"?

Why would you select one over the other?

Comment: Please see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221661.aspx)

Comment: What is the context in which you are asking this question?

Answer (score 27):

"In-process" means the component runs in the same process space as the one using it.
"Out-process" means the component runs in a different process space compared to the one using it. The two processes may be running on the same machine also. What matters is that they are not sharing the same process space.

The difference is the way in which you need to communicate with the component based on how it is running:

- In case of in-process, you communicate using local method calls.
- In case of out-process, you need to have some remote-procedure-call mechanism used on both the sides. E.g. Java's RMI is one such protocol. Microsoft's COM is one such protocol.

Answer (score 8):

- In process is one where it runs on the local machine i.e within the Application
- Out process is one where it runs on a server i.e outside the application